# Fast way to make list with same entry multiple times in Python?

Tags: python, list

Is there an elegant way in python to make a list of duplicate things?

For example, I want to make a list of 7 lefts, like so:

```
x = ['left', 'left', 'left', 'left', 'left', 'left', 'left']
```

other than doing something like:

```
x = []
for y in xrange(7):
    x.append('left')
```

is there a way to efficiently make a list of 7 lefts? I had hoped for something like:
`x = ['left' * 7]`, but of course that gives me `['leftleftleftleftleftleftleft']`.

Thanks a lot,
Alex

Comment: Yeah, looks like that's pretty much the same question, sorry.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want (or simply are okay with) a list of references to the same object, list multiplication is what you want:

```
x = ['left'] * 7
```

If you need separate objects, e.g. if you're initializing a list of lists, you want a list comprehension:

```
x = [[] for _ in xrange(7)]
```

Answer (score 3):

What about something like `x = ['left'] * 7`?

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> list = ['left' for x in range(7)]
>>> list
>>>['left', 'left', 'left', 'left', 'left', 'left', 'left']
```

Answer (score 1):

`['left'] * 7`

or

`[ 'left' for _dummy in range(7) ]`

Answer (score 0):

Lost comprehension

```
['Left' for _ in range(7)]
```